# Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, tiles

a new Problem.
After i fixed an Array, this erro comes up:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5   at
>   de.gandalf1783.Level.getTilesTouched(Level.java:37)   at
>   de.gandalf1783.Creature.move(Creature.java:33)    at
>   de.gandalf1783.Player.update(Player.java:19)  at
>   de.gandalf1783.Game.update(Game.java:84)  at
>   de.gandalf1783.Game.run(Game.java:54)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

Here is the Level class:
package de.gandalf1783;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Level {
  private TileSet[] ts;
  private int sizeX, sizeY;
  private int[][][] tileMap;
  private Game game;

  public Level(Game game, String path, TileSet[] ts1) {
    this.game = game;
    this.ts = ts1;
    String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
    String[] tokens = file.split("\\s");
    sizeY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    tileMap = new int[1][sizeX][sizeY];
    int i = 2;
    for(int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
      for(int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++){
        tileMap[1][x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[i++]);
      }
    }
  }

  public void renderMap(Graphics g){
    for(int tileY = 0; tileY < sizeY; tileY++){
      for(int tileX = 0; tileX < sizeX; tileX++){
        ts[0].renderTile(g, tileMap[0][tileX][tileY], tileX * TileSet.TILEWIDTH - game.getGameCamera().getxOffset(),
                  tileY * TileSet.TILEHEIGHT - game.getGameCamera().getyOffset());
      }
    }
  }
  public int[][] getTilesTouched(Creature player) {
    int[][] ret = new int[1][2];
    int numX = (player.entityX + Player.MARGIN_HORIZ) / player.width;
    int numY = (player.entityY + player.height - Player.MARGIN_VERT) / player.height;
    ret[0][0] = tileMap[0][numX][numY];
    if(ts[0].hs.contains(ret[0][0])) {
      ret[0][0] <<= 16;
    }
    numX = (player.entityX + player.width - Player.MARGIN_HORIZ) / player.width;
    ret[0][1] = tileMap[0][numX][numY];
    if(ts[0].hs.contains(ret[0][1])) {
      ret[0][1] <<= 16;
    }
    return ret;
  }

public int getSizeX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sizeX;
}
public int getSizeY() {
    return sizeY;
}
}
```

It says the program is interupting cause the array is empty there, or am i wrong?

**EDIT 1:**
The method that is causing Problems:

```
     public int[][] getTilesTouched(Creature player) {
    int[][] ret = new int[1][2];
    int numX = (player.entityX + Player.MARGIN_HORIZ) / player.width;
    int numY = (player.entityY + player.height - Player.MARGIN_VERT) / player.height;
    ret[0][0] = tileMap[0][numX][numY];
    if(ts[0].hs.contains(ret[0][0])) {
      ret[0][0] <<= 16;
    }
    numX = (player.entityX + player.width - Player.MARGIN_HORIZ) / player.width;
    ret[0][1] = tileMap[0][numX][numY];
    if(ts[0].hs.contains(ret[0][1])) {
      ret[0][1] <<= 16;
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

And here the line that is causing problems (line 37):

```
ret[0][0] = tileMap[0][numX][numY]
```

Comment: Actually, the "getTilesTouched" is there to check of the tiles are touched, and if yes which one(s).

Comment: What line is line 37? Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program?

Comment: line 37:
    ret[0][0] = tileMap[0][numX][numY];

Comment: Please read: [Why is "can somebody help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `sizeX` seems to be never assigned a valid value.
Its first usage is here, and that will result in `[1][0][whatever]`

```
tileMap = new int[1][sizeX][sizeY];
```

Then, here

```
ret[0][0] = tileMap[0][numX][numY];
```

it does throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, obviously.

You might want to assign both `sizeX` and `sizeY` inside `Level` constructor

```
final String[] tokens = file.split("\\s");
sizeX = Utils.parseInt(tokens[0]);
sizeY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
```

I suppose this is what you want.

Comment: And where should i  write it? In the method its not working.

Comment: Thanks, but i managed to do it myself. I just replaced the code from the tutorial with my one and it worked fine. You could take look at my new question.

Comment: @Gandalf1783 I'll look at it tomorrow as I'm going to sleep now